# opencv c++ ORB Bag Of Words

Tags: c++, opencv, orb

After reading [this paper](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FCostantino_Grana%2Fpublication%2F236010493_A_Fast_Approach_for_Integrating_ORB_Descriptors_in_the_Bag_of_Words_Model%2Flinks%2F00463515abb8070843000000.pdf&ei=8V7TVI_6FqOv7Abg34D4CA&usg=AFQjCNFCB5cmaI0fw9AuXcx3adMpiJoGRQ&sig2=ikKBty-B1-2CHJzONPVJCg&bvm=bv.85142067,d.ZGU), as well as many `answers.opencv` questions, I was wondering if there was any code examples out there of an ORB Bag Of Words? I could only find `SURF` or `SIFT` examples.

Comment: for BOW, unfortunately only sift and surf (float descriptors) are appropriate due to l2 distance used in kmeans clustering.

Comment: So how did they achieve it?

Comment: ^^ by replacing the kmeans part with a different algorithm, clustering descriptors with hamming distance, and recalculating the cluster centers via majority voting

Comment: I misread what you said* thought you meant only sift and surf were appropriate, ie bow can only work with those 2.

Comment: ok, let's clarify that: opencv's builtin BagOfWords training classes will only work with sift or surf, if you want a similar idea for ORB or BRIEF, you will have to implement that similar to the paper you mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no example of using Bag-Of-Words with binary descriptors (BRIEF, **ORB**, BRISK, FREAK). Either way the paper you showed explains how you can do it. For traditional descriptors (SIFT, SURF) the k-means clustering technique is used because the vocabulary is generated from a set of real valued descriptors. However to obtain a binary vocabulary, k-means method is not ideal because mean is not defined in binary space, then you can use the k-majority method.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to cluster binary features in OpenCV is using FLANN with Hamming distance. To my knowledge no example exist, because it would require first fixing a bug in OpenCv's Hamming distance function [[1](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6355)].
This is my code for it, where `cvhack::Hamming<uchar>` is a bug-fixed Hamming distance.

```
    cvflann::KMeansIndexParams params;  
    cv::Mat centres = cv::Mat::zeros(dictionarySize, features.cols, CV_32F);
    int count = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<uchar,cvhack::Hamming<uchar>>(features,centres,params);
```